# .htaccess Not Working Properly In IE

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My .htaccess file is not working in IE, It works fine in FireFox and Chrome, but in IE images wont load, and links don't work correctly ether. The CSS works fine and all the PHP seams to be working aswell.

I am pretty sure that it has something to do with me needing to pull 2 GET variables from the url, because it works fine when I only need to pull one variable. Anyway here is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /website/index.php?id=$1&c=$2
```

Please help, I have been looking for hours for a solution for this.

Comment: Are you using a `<base>` tag in the header of your pages?

Comment: yes, does it have to be in the <head></head>?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how ANY rewrite conditions would be browser dependent.. 
your problem must be somewhere else.

maybe try removing the leading / from your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /website/index.php?id=$1&c=$2
```

Comment: any suggestion on where it might be? Everything is working except for images and links, for example, lets say the base url is localhost/website/148/category and I click a link that should take me to localhost/website/149/category it takes me to localhost/website/148/category/149/category. So it is just adding onto the url it seams.

Comment: the link is <a href="', $image['id'] + 1, '/' ,$catagory, '">

Comment: and the image src is <img src="images/next.png">

Comment: I tried the new rule you posted and it doesn't break it but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: well.. as i said, without seeing any actual code i can only guess.... <a href="', $image['id'] + 1, '/' ,$catagory, '"> what's with the "," btw? that probably kills IE

Comment: the link is being echoed out: echo '<a href="', $image['id'] + 1, '/' ,$catagory, '"><img src="images/next.png"></a>';

Comment: so if the link is "images/next.png", (did you check in the html of IE? (press F12)) is this the correct link? what does IE actually request?

Comment: Yeah I checked that, it is going to the right directory, I also compared it to FireFox and it was the same.

Comment: Alright I got it working, I just had to add /website/ in front of my links and image src

Comment: oh.. and the rewrite rule didn't work because there was no 2nd / in the link.. now i see it :D makes me wonder tho why it worked on firefox... seems firefox sends a request string different from IE.

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is working except for images and links, for example, lets say the base url is localhost/website/148/category and I click a link that should take me to localhost/website/149/category it takes me to localhost/website/148/category/149/category. So it is just adding onto the url it seams.

This is a relative/absolute URI issue, and not anything to do with your rewrite rules. Using the `<base>` tag is supposed to fix this but there's [bugs in versions of IE8](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/c51bb8b9-40ab-437b-a125-88b660f3e1ca/) which causes it to be ignored without a FQDN in front, something like:

```
<base href="http://localhost/website/">
```

(Not even really sure if that fixes the issue).

And yes, it needs to be before all other references and inside the `<head> </head>` tags. The only other recourse to fixing this is changing all your links to absolute URI's instead of relative ones.

Comment: I got it working, I had the <base> tag already set but for some reason it completely ignored part of the page, maybe it was because I was echoing out the links and images.